# Adaptive Cards: Slack downrendering of AdaptiveCards not working

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, slack-api, adaptive-cards

We are using AdaptiveCards.We have this working in both channels (Slack and Web), even in slack the adptive card appear as an image while web mode appears in text.

Since this week, slack adptive card is not working, whenever we make a request to show the card it appears the space of the image but the image does not have any content.

I already request support, but regarding I need to close this, I would request if someone face the same problem and how to solve that.

We are using last version of BotBuilder: 3.12.2.4

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3823)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue discussed at https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/985. It seems a Windows update affected the WPF rendering used by Adaptive Cards, thus sometimes it fails delivering a blank image.

The `Adaptive Cards` team is still managing the rollout and patching.

**Update 12/6**

This is now fixed.